# Material-UI SelectField onChange doesnt work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make work `material-ui` `SelectField` component.

In my project common `select` component work without problems, but if declare `SelectField` component I have problem.

The problem is with calling `onChange` method.

If I call it with `Select` component all works, value is changed on click and

> test

is written into console.

If I call it with `SelectField` component. In `GUI` it only shows items from `subsystemsItems` variable, but if I try to select one nothing happens.

> test

is also not written into console.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      SubsystemID: ''
    };
    this.handleSelectChange6 = this.handleSelectChange6.bind(this);
  }

  handleSelectChange6(event) {

    console.log("test");
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    if (value === "Zvolit") {
      this.setState({
        [name]: ''
      });
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        [name]: value
      });
    }

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectField
          value={this.state.SubsystemID}
          onChange={this.handleSelectChange6}>
          {subsystemsItems}
        </SelectField>

        <select value={this.state.SubsystemID} name={"SubsystemID"} onChange={this.handleSelectChange6}>
          <option defaultValue>Zvolit</option>
          {subsystemsItems}
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of material-ui do you use

Comment: "material-ui": "^0.20.1",

Comment: You children to SelectField cannot be option but `MenuItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `<MenuItem>` component provided by material-ui

```
<SelectField
   value={this.state.SubsystemID}
   onChange={this.handleSelectChange6}>
      {
          subsystemsItems.map((option, key) => (
               <MenuItem key={key} value={option.value} primaryText={option.label} />
          ))          
      }
</SelectField>
```

Comment: well, now i have console output. Can you please help me to get "Name" attribute from SelectField to handle change?

Comment: SelectField doesn's provide name property, but you can do something like this:

`onChange={(event, index, value) => this. handleSelectChange6(value, 'myField')}`

where `myField` is the string you want to identify your field with. Then you can just add this param to `handleSelectChange6(event, name)`

Comment: now i have issue that i dont see selected item in SelectField. I properly set my variable after selection. attribute value doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, change your `handleSelectChange6` definition to accept `(value, name)` instead only `event`

Comment: now, after loading page it show preselected last item. if i select something, i am possible to change variable in this.state.SubsystemID, but it doesnt change in SelectField

Comment: <SelectField 
  value={this.state.SubsystemID}
   onChange={(event) => this.handleSelectChange6(event, "SubsystemID")}>
   
      {
          subsystemsItems.map((option, key) => (
               <MenuItem key={key} value={this.state.SubsystemID}  primaryText={option} />
          ))          
      }

Comment: You can set a nullable option in `subsystemsItems` like {value: null, label: ''} to have a default empty. See all examples at [docs](https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field)

Comment: problem is that when i select something it doesnt change in GUI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173879/discussion-between-marcos-b-and-bobek).